# Dependency injection in a Keystone middleware (openstack)

Tags: python, openstack, middleware, keystone

In my keystone middleware, i'm trying to call the assignment_api function get_project_by_name.

I'm trying to do so by using a dependency injection, but instead, i'm seeing the following error in the debug log:

> AttributeError: 'ProjectsByDemand' object has no attribute
>   'assignment_api'

See the code below:

```
from keystone.openstack.common import log as logging
from keystone.common import dependency
from keystone import config
from keystone import exception
from keystone.common import cache
from keystone.common import wsgi

@dependency.requires('assignment_api')
class ProjectsByDemand(wsgi.Middleware):
  def __init__(self, app, conf):
    self.conf = conf
    self.app = app
    self.internal_l = ['admin','neutron','glance','cinder','nova']
    self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

   .
   .
   .

  def process_request(self, environ, start_response):
    auth = self.get_username(environ)
    if auth is not None:
      if auth[0] is not self.internal_l:
        self.log.debug('middleware-debug: Authenticating with: %s' % (auth[0]) )
        project_ref = self.assignment_api.get_project_by_name(username, "default")
        self.log.debug("middleware-debug: Project ref is: %s", project_ref)
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Any idea what is it that's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the tabs and spaces and also you bungled the indentation please try to run the script with `python -tt` to check that.